# Android NDEF Push Failing

Tags: android, nfc

I am doing an NDEF push (android v2.3.4) of a 62 byte NDEF packet. This push fails. However, if I adjust the packet size to 58, its goes thru fine. 58 seems to be some kind of limit.

These are my logs:

I have tried a 59 byte NDEF packet, but it fails.

```
I/NFC JNI (  186): LLCP Link activated (LTO=132, MIU=256, OPTION=0x03, WKS=0x03)
D/NdefPushClient(  186): LLCP connection up and running
D/NdefPushClient(  186): sending foreground
D/NdefPushClient(  186): about to create socket
D/NdefPushClient(  186): about to connect to service com.android.npp
D/dalvikvm(  109): GC_EXPLICIT freed 186K, 47% free 5325K/9927K, external 4760K/5615K, paused 112ms
D/NdefPushClient(  186): about to send a 59 byte message
D/NdefPushClient(  186): about to send a 59 byte packet
I/NFC JNI (  186): LLCP Link deactivated
E/NdefPushClient(  186): couldn't send tag
D/NfcService(  186): LLCP Link Deactivated message. Restart polling loop.
D/NdefPushClient(  186): exception:
D/NdefPushClient(  186): java.io.IOException
D/NdefPushClient(  186):    at com.android.internal.nfc.LlcpSocket.send(LlcpSocket.java:172)
D/NdefPushClient(  186):    at com.android.nfc.ndefpush.NdefPushClient$SendAsync.doInBackground(NdefPushClient.java:123)
D/NdefPushClient(  186):    at com.android.nfc.ndefpush.NdefPushClient$SendAsync.doInBackground(NdefPushClient.java:99)
D/NdefPushClient(  186):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
D/NdefPushClient(  186):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
D/NdefPushClient(  186):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
D/NdefPushClient(  186):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
D/NdefPushClient(  186):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
D/NdefPushClient(  186):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
D/NdefPushClient(  186): about to close
```

then the link is dropped automatically.
any ideas as to why this happens?

cheers,
Earlence

Comment: does this happens all the time, or was this a one-shot error? The line 172 in llcpsocket.java raises an ioexception if the internal send fails.

Comment: It happens all the time. I think this is some sort of bug in the stack.

Comment: what kind of tag are you pushing to?

Comment: I am pushing to an ARYGON reader that implements the NPP protocol.

Comment: If you're using Android 2.3.3, and your Arygon-reader supports AGF-Frames this could be the problem. The standard Android 2.3.3 NFC stack has this problem, but it has been fixed in the 2.3.4 release.

Comment: I am using Android 2.3.4 so it should not matter whether the reader supports AGF frames, right?